# Looping through array doesnt seem to work

Tags: c

This program supposed to go through the file and when character matches one of the given patterns assign either 0 or 1 to its array cell. And later display hidden message from spaces and stars. But it assigns either 0 or 1 to all cells in the array based on the last character in the file.

EXAMPLE FILE TO LOOP THROUGH(30A.dat):
ZuVbJJgFyMuVaXsRkgPuHJmNgiNPFJmHDVRFmPcNLgDykaFugooidgyBhgNEsVdXCcsaYyaYQEGsNhpIxOJHyFjluiNvoFJLSTRVlEPPHGNowGeavuRnNySivmuQXXLgxDKRXPutaBOgNYiZvtPwoYHXEFcrVVOJwirHoOwmxDqFILoHfygqNcBfXLsDMXtNymytqEgCeoMoIosuctXbsmDUsmfBwzJqBMyTHjaunrlTWjzxMuBhvUGIxRAqcrFheCGUzlhLKeLHAcsvaZCaNyzuwiMgkVBbLzBHPUiXlXDXTIwjqTHvIeWFTXLdDYccceSQBfIXDagvZPesYQdjeeUVZVqdyxPcFwxaWJywgWXviFkyKoz

```
int tab_a[a][c];

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while((znak = fgetc(plik2)) != EOF){
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
            if((znak == 'a') || 
                 (znak == 'B') || 
                 (znak == 'c') || 
                 (znak == 'D') || 
                 (znak == 'e') || 
                 (znak == 'F') || 
                 (znak == 'g') || 
                 (znak == 'H') || 
                 (znak == 'i') || 
                 (znak == 'J') || 
                 (znak == 'k') || 
                 (znak == 'L') || 
                 (znak == 'm') || 
                 (znak == 'N') || 
                 (znak == 'o') || 
                 (znak == 'P') || 
                 (znak == 'q') || 
                 (znak == 'R') || 
                 (znak == 's') || 
                 (znak == 'T') || 
                 (znak == 'u') || 
                 (znak == 'V') || 
                 (znak == 'w') || 
                 (znak == 'X') || 
                 (znak == 'y') || 
                 (znak == 'Z'))
                {
                    tab_a[i][j] = 0;
                }
            else if((znak == 'A') || 
                        (znak == 'b') || 
                            (znak == 'C') || 
                            (znak == 'd') || 
                            (znak == 'E') || 
                            (znak == 'f') || 
                            (znak == 'G') || 
                            (znak == 'h') || 
                            (znak == 'I') || 
                            (znak == 'j') || 
                            (znak == 'K') || 
                            (znak == 'l') || 
                            (znak == 'M') || 
                            (znak == 'n') || 
                            (znak == 'O') || 
                            (znak == 'p') || 
                            (znak == 'Q') || 
                            (znak == 'r') || 
                            (znak == 'S') || 
                            (znak == 't') || 
                            (znak == 'U') || 
                            (znak == 'v') || 
                            (znak == 'W') || 
                            (znak == 'x') || 
                            (znak == 'Y') || 
                            (znak == 'z'))
                {
                    tab_a[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
        if(tab_a[i][j] == 1){
            printf("*");
        }
        else{
            printf(" ");
        }
     }
     printf("\n");
}

fclose(plik);
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Consider posting a [mcve]

Comment: Create look-up tables instead of this.

Comment: Just by looking on this code for 5 seconds I can tell you that the number of lines of this code can probably be divided by a factor of 8 or so.

Comment: What result do you want to achieve? Should `i`  and `j` somehow correspond to the characters of the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work.
Create an array of valid characters.
Read a character from the file into `znak`.
`strchr` will check to see if `znak` is one of the valid characters.
If so, set a zero. If not, set a one.
Increment `j`. If `j` is equal to `c`, reset `j` to zero and increment `i`.
Read another character.
When `i` is equal to `a`, the array is full. `Break` out of the loop.

```
char valid[] = "aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ";
while ( (znak = fgetc(plik2)) != EOF) {
    if ( strchr ( valid, znak)) {
        tab_a[i][j] = 0;
    }
    else {
        tab_a[i][j] = 1;
    }
    j++;
    if ( j >= c) {
        j = 0;
        i++;
        if ( i >= a) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it does that:

For ***each*** character read, iterare over ***all*** array elements and for each check if the character read is in a-zA-Z. If so, (and that will always be true) then set the array element to 0 or 1 as per your if statements. In effect the array values will all be based on the last character read.

Now, what you really want is unclear so I can't give a full solution.